# Is it possible to put an entire module function's arguments in a pillar?

Tags: salt-stack

Consider the following state to install a package (taken from `pkg.installed` documentation):

```
httpd:
  pkg.installed:
    - fromrepo: mycustomrepo
    - skip_verify: True
    - skip_suggestions: True
    - version: 2.0.6~ubuntu3
    - refresh: True
    - cache_valid_time: 300
    - allow_updates: True
    - hold: False
```

Is it possible to move the `pkg.installed` arguments into a pillar file like so:

```
pkg:
  install:
    - name: httpd
      fromrepo: mycustomrepo
      skip_verify: True
      skip_suggestions: True
      version: 2.0.6~ubuntu3
      refresh: True
      cache_valid_time: 300
      allow_updates: True
      hold: False
```

And then create a generic state to install package(s) like this:

```
{% for p in salt['pillar.get']('pkg:install') %}
install_{{ p.name }}:
  pkg.installed:
    {{ p }}
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously, this example doesn't work because `{{ p }}` is a `dict` and `pkg.installed` expects a `list`, but hopefully this makes clear what I am trying to accomplish.

Now imagine a scenario where I have 5 different applications running on 5 different minions that all require the `httpd` package, but they all require different arguments. Maybe they all use different versions and one of them doesn't supply the `refresh` argument. What's the best way to handle this?

Right now, my only option is to write 5 different states, or write one state that has a bunch of ugly conditionals:

```
{% for p in salt['pillar.get']('pkg:install') %}
install_{{ p.name }}:
  pkg.installed:
    {% if p.fromrepo is defined %}
    - fromrepo: {{ p.fromrepo }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if p.refresh is defined %}
    - refresh: {{ p.refresh }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I realize I can create defaults for some of these arguments, but that doesn't work for arguments like `version` and `fromrepo` (what would I default these to?). So is there anyway to accomplish what I am trying to do or should I go back to the drawing board and re-think my entire approach?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, I found an example in a salt-formula researching something completely unrelated.

Assuming a pillar file setup like so:

```
pkg:
  install:
    - name: httpd
      fromrepo: mycustomrepo
      skip_verify: True
      version: 2.0.6~ubuntu3
    - name: python38
      skip_suggestions: True
      hold: True
    - name: java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

This will iterate all dictionaries in `pkg:install` and then iterate each dictionary to apply the key/value pairs:

```
{% for p in pkgs %}
install_{{ p.name }}_package:
  pkg.installed:
    {%- for k, v in p.items() %}
    - {{ k }}: {{ v }}
    {%- endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It's a pretty simple solution, I was overthinking it.